# Python multiprocessing.Manager().Queue() is preventing clean exit, how do I fix it?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I use a `ProcessPoolExecutor` to handle [CPU-bound tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51829082/9698467).

I initialize each Process to [ignore the KeyboardInterrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44869451/9698467) signal because I have `try-except` where I call `ppex.shutdown()` method to gracefully stop all processes.

Because I use processes instead of threads, I am [sending all logs to a Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes) and then a separate Thread in the MainProcess pops messages from the Queue and prints them on stdout.

The [official suggestion](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-concurrent-futures-processpoolexecutor) is to use `multiprocessing.Manager().Queue(-1)`. However, when I press `CTRL+C` in the terminal, the exiting hangs. If I change the queue to `multiprocessing.Queue(-1)`, everything works fine.

What's wrong and how do I fix it?

```
import logging
import multiprocessing
import os
import signal
import threading
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from logging.handlers import QueueHandler

def queue_consumer(queue: multiprocessing.Queue):
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    while True:
        try:
            record = queue.get()
            if record is None:  # We send this to tell the consumer thread to quit.
                break
            handler.handle(record)
        except Exception:
            import sys, traceback
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr)

def setup_logging(queue: multiprocessing.Queue) -> threading.Thread:
    format = "%(asctime)s %(processName)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=format, handlers=[QueueHandler(queue)])
    # take queue processing into a separate thread
    qc = threading.Thread(target=queue_consumer, args=(queue,))
    qc.start()
    return qc

def process_init():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)

def task(i: int):
    logging.info(f"Received task {i}")
    time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue(-1) # <-- THIS LINE IS THE PROBLEM
    # THIS WORKS: multiprocessing.Queue(-1)
    qc = setup_logging(queue)
    logging.info("Started.")
    # make childprocesses ignore CTRL+C, because shutdown is governed gracefully
    ppex = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=max(os.cpu_count()-1, 1),
                               initializer=process_init)
    try:
        while True:
            for i in range(3):
                ppex.submit(task, i)
            time.sleep(5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logging.info("Shutting down and wait a bit...")
        # close the ProcessPoolExecutor gracefully
        ppex.shutdown(wait=True, cancel_futures=True)
        logging.info("Everything is stopped successfully.")
        queue.put_nowait(None)
        qc.join()
```